# Is zookeeper reconfig expected to update the zoo.cfg.dynamic file?

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I'm setting up a distributed cluster for ZooKeeper based on version 3.5.2. In specific, I'm utilizing the [reconfig](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.5.2-alpha/zookeeperReconfig.html) command to dynamically update the configuration when there is any rebalance in the cluster (e.g. one of the nodes comes down).

The observation I have is that the zoo.cfg.dynamic file is not getting updated even when the reconfig (add/remove) command is correctly executed. Is this the expected behavior ? Basically I'm looking for guidance whether we should manage the zoo.cfg.dynamic file also through a separate script (update it lock-step with the reconfig command) or can we rely on the reconfig command to do this for us. My preference/expectation is the latter.

Following is the sample command:
`reconfig -remove 6 -add server.5=125.23.63.23:1234:1235;1236`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [reconfig documentation](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.5.2-alpha/zookeeperReconfig.html#sc_reconfig_file):

> Dynamic configuration parameters are stored in a separate file on the server (which we call the dynamic configuration file). **This file is linked from the static config file using the new dynamicConfigFile keyword**.

So I could practically start with any file name to host the ensemble list and ensure the 'dynamicConfigFile' config keyword just point to this file.

Now when the reconfig command is run, basically a new dynamic-config file (e.g. zoo.cfg.dynamic.00000112) is generated which contains the transformed list of servers, in the form as below (as an example):

> server.1=125.23.63.23:2780:2783:participant;2791
>   server.2=125.23.63.24:2781:2784:participant;2792
>   server.3=125.23.63.25:2782:2785:participant;2793

The zoo.cfg file is hence auto-updated to point the 'dynamicConfigFile' config keyword to the new config file (zoo.cfg.dynamic.00000112). The previous dynamic-config file continues to be available in the runtime (config directory) but it is not being referred by the main config anymore.

So overall, there is no overhead to update any file lock-step to the reconfig command i.e. reconfig command takes care of it all. The only potential overhead to upfront resolve is to write a periodic purge of the old dynamic-config files.